# creating a Javascript voting system

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my attempt at a voting system. It works as expected when there is only one. However, when I try to scale the number of voting systems beyond one it doesn't work as expected. The problem is that the voting system relies on the `upVote` and `downVote` state. So, when I increase the number of voting systems, they all rely on the same two variables, instead of each having their own `upVote` and `downVote` variables. There are two ways I think I can solve my problem.

1. Create an array so each voting system has their own `upVote` and `downVote` variables.
2. Use closure.

The first one I think is too cumbersome and unpractical I don't what to implement this solution. The second one I tried but couldn't get it to work.

I couldn't think of anything simpler. I'm not necessarily looking for a solution that uses closure. Any  simple **vanilla Javascript** solution is fine.

The working code:

```js
const up_vote_span = document.querySelector('.up-vote');
const down_vote_span = document.querySelector('.down-vote');
let count = document.querySelector('.number');

let upVote = false;
let downVote = false;

up_vote_span.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (downVote === true) {

    up_vote_span.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
    down_vote_span.style.color = "dimgray";
    count.innerHTML = parseInt(count.innerHTML) + 2;
    upVote = true;
    downVote = false;

  } else if (upVote === false) {
    up_vote_span.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
    count.innerHTML = parseInt(count.innerHTML) + 1;
    upVote = true;
  } else if (upVote === true) {
    up_vote_span.style.color = "dimgray";
    count.innerHTML = parseInt(count.innerHTML) - 1;
    upVote = false;
  }
});

down_vote_span.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (upVote === true) {
    up_vote_span.style.color = "dimgray";
    down_vote_span.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
    count.innerHTML = parseInt(count.innerHTML) - 2;
    downVote = true;
    upVote = false;
  } else if (downVote === false) {
    down_vote_span.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
    count.innerHTML = parseInt(count.innerHTML) - 1;
    downVote = true;
  } else if (downVote === true) {
    down_vote_span.style.color = "dimgray";
    count.innerHTML = parseInt(count.innerHTML) + 1;
    downVote = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.vote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.up-vote {
  color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down-vote {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
```

The problematic code:

```js
const up_vote_span = document.getElementsByClassName('up-vote');
const down_vote_span = document.getElementsByClassName('down-vote');
const count = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

let upVote = false;
let downVote = false;

for (let i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  up_vote_span[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (downVote === true) {
      up_vote_span[i].style.color = "#3CBC8D";
      down_vote_span[i].style.color = "dimgray";
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) + 2;
      upVote = true;
      downVote = false;

    } else if (upVote === false) {
      up_vote_span[i].style.color = "#3CBC8D";
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) + 1;
      upVote = true;
    } else if (upVote === true) {
      up_vote_span[i].style.color = "dimgray";
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) - 1;
      upVote = false;
    }
  });

  down_vote_span[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (upVote === true) {
      up_vote_span[i].style.color = "dimgray";
      down_vote_span[i].style.color = "#3CBC8D";
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) - 2;
      downVote = true;
      upVote = false;
    } else if (downVote === false) {
      down_vote_span[i].style.color = "#3CBC8D";
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) - 1;
      downVote = true;
    } else if (downVote === true) {
      down_vote_span[i].style.color = "dimgray";
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) + 1;
      downVote = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.vote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.up-vote {
  color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down-vote {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you please create fiddle and share link here

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle before. Is it possible to do that without signing up?

Comment: @Spanishbeginner Yes you can and I just made one for you, the working one: https://jsfiddle.net/vepg5s30/ the problematic one: https://jsfiddle.net/d7L0a3g9/

Comment: Can you explain your problem little more, while clicking up arrow u need to increase and down arrow decrease is it??

Comment: Are you okay with using es6 classes? you can run it on most major browsers! https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Comment: @ Shibon in the problematic code try this: up-vote the first system. Then try to upvote the second system. what will happen is that the second system is actually down-voted. this is because they are all sharing the same two Boolean variables that determines the state of a system. but the fact that the two states are being shared is what is causing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Mohammed. no I'm not :( there are a lot of es6 goodies i'm not familiar with.

Comment: Look up OOP with es6 classes it will make your life easier. You should be able to create a single class and make multiple instances of it which each one of them has its own self-controlled state.

Comment: @Mohammed you've been able to do that before ES6, too, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find this easier to control and think about if you go with the array method you mentioned as option #1 and then make a single function for upvoting and a single function for downvoting instead of creating separate functions for every single up and down arrow like you are doing now.

You have four groups right now, so inside your `for` loop we can initialize an array like this:

```
const votes = [
  0: { up: false, down: false },
  1: { up: false, down: false },
  2: { up: false, down: false },
  3: { up: false, down: false },
];
```

Then you can just call your up- and down-voting functions and check the value of the object in that array that corresponds to the group number of the arrow you clicked.

The other thing that I think helps readability is separating out changing the vote total from the color changes.

Your vote logic includes three distinct possibilities, 1.) arrow was already checked, 2.) opposite arrow was checked, and 3.) neither arrow was checked. But your color-changing logic and the logic for changing the checked value of each arrow really only has two possibilities: either the arrow was checked before or it wasn't.

So I went ahead and made that change in the below snippet as well.

Hope this helps.

```js
const up_vote_spans = document.getElementsByClassName('up-vote');
const down_vote_spans = document.getElementsByClassName('down-vote');
const count = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

let votes = [];

for (let i = 0; i < count.length; i += 1) {
  const thisUpVoteSpan = up_vote_spans[i];
  const thisDownVoteSpan = down_vote_spans[i];
  votes[i] = { up: false, down: false };

  thisUpVoteSpan.addEventListener('click', handleUpvote.bind(null, i), false);
  thisDownVoteSpan.addEventListener('click', handleDownvote.bind(null, i), false);
}

function handleUpvote(i) {
  const currentVote = votes[i];
  const matchingUpSpan = up_vote_spans[i];
  const matchingDownSpan = down_vote_spans[i];
  const matchingCount = count[i];
  const currentCount = parseInt(matchingCount.innerHTML);

  if (currentVote.down) {
    matchingCount.innerHTML = currentCount + 2;
  } else if (currentVote.up === false) {
    matchingCount.innerHTML = currentCount + 1;
  } else {
    matchingCount.innerHTML = currentCount - 1;
  }
  if (!currentVote.up) {
    matchingUpSpan.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
    matchingDownSpan.style.color = 'dimgray';
    currentVote.up = true;
    currentVote.down = false;
  } else {
    matchingUpSpan.style.color = 'dimgray';
    currentVote.up = false;
  }
}

function handleDownvote(i) {
  const currentVote = votes[i];
  const matchingUpSpan = up_vote_spans[i];
  const matchingDownSpan = down_vote_spans[i];
  const matchingCount = count[i];
  const currentCount = parseInt(matchingCount.innerHTML);

  if (currentVote.up) {
    matchingCount.innerHTML = currentCount - 2;
  } else if (currentVote.down === false) {
    matchingCount.innerHTML = currentCount - 1;
  } else {
    matchingCount.innerHTML = currentCount + 1;
  }
  if (!currentVote.down) {
    matchingDownSpan.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
    matchingUpSpan.style.color = 'dimgray';
    currentVote.down = true;
    currentVote.up = false;
  } else {
    matchingDownSpan.style.color = 'dimgray';
    currentVote.down = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.vote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.up-vote {
  color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.down-vote {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="vote">
    <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
    <span class="number">990</span>
    <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are right the array method was easy to follow and less cumbersome that I though it would be.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the [Prototype Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/prototype-design-pattern) to organize the code.

This will work for `n` `.vote` classes in the `HTML`. For example, given the following `HTML`, two vote objects will be created and associated with their respective UI.

```html
<div class="vote">
  <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
  <span class="number">0</span>
  <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="vote">
  <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
  <span class="number">0</span>
  <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
```

You might have noticed that there are no `id`s in the above `HTML`. The `id`s are created dynamically in a `forEach` loop and assigned on `init` of each object. I'm using `myVotePrototype` as a template, copying its `prototype` into each new object created in `myVote`. `myVote` takes an `id` to initialize, which is how each vote knows where to find its associated UI piece.

### What about colors?

The `JavaScript` sets the voting direction in the `.vote` parent container. So, after an up-vote, the `HTML` for that vote object would look like this:

```html
<div class="vote vote-up">
  <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
  <span class="number">0</span>
  <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
```

I added a little `CSS` so that each button knows when to assume the active color. I found this less messy than writing the hex code directly to a `style` attribute.

```css
.vote.vote-up .up-vote,
.vote.vote-down .down-vote {
  color: #3CBC8D;
}
```

### Demo

```js
const myVotePrototype = {
  init: function(id) {
    this.voteId = id;
    // Prepare for voting clicks
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  votes: 0,
  upVote: function() {
    this.votes++;
    this.setVoteDirection('up');
  },
  downVote: function() {
    this.votes--;
    this.setVoteDirection('down');
  },
  setVoteDirection: function(direction) {
    let voteObj = document.getElementById(this.voteId);
    if (direction === 'up') {
      voteObj.classList.add('vote-up');
      if (voteObj.classList.contains('vote-down')) {
        voteObj.classList.remove('vote-down');
      }
    } else if (direction === 'down') {
      voteObj.classList.add('vote-down');
      if (voteObj.classList.contains('vote-up')) {
        voteObj.classList.remove('vote-up');
      }      
    }
  },
  updateUI: function() {
    document.querySelector(`#${this.voteId} .number`).innerHTML = Number(this.votes);
  },
  bindEvents: function() {
    document
      .querySelector(`#${this.voteId} .up-vote`)
      .addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.upVote();
        this.updateUI();
      });
    document
      .querySelector(`#${this.voteId} .down-vote`)
      .addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.downVote();
        this.updateUI();
      })
  }
};

function myVote(id) {
  function V() {};
  V.prototype = myVotePrototype;

  let v = new V();

  v.init(id);
  return v;
}

// Loop through all votes in the UI
const votes = document.querySelectorAll('.vote');
votes.forEach((vote, index) => {
  // Create an id
  let voteId = `vote_${index}`;
  // Set the id in the UI so we can find it later for updating
  vote.setAttribute('id', voteId);
  // Create a new vote object, passing in the vote id
  myVote(voteId);
});
```

```css
.number {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.vote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.up-vote,
.down-vote {
  color: dimgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vote.vote-up .up-vote,
.vote.vote-down .down-vote {
  color: #3CBC8D;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="vote">
  <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
  <span class="number">0</span>
  <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="vote">
  <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
  <span class="number">0</span>
  <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="vote">
  <span class="up-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></span>
  <span class="number">0</span>
  <span class="down-vote"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></span>
</div>
```

**Ideas for improvement**

- Semantic, accessible `HTML` (`<button>` instead of `<span>`)
- Use of [ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/) to associate `button`s with `number` output
- `localStorage` to remember vote states between page loads (or use a real `DB` :))

Comment: I really like this answer. However, with my limited skills its a bit hard to follow. I will be using this to improve my coding skills and possible use this style once I can understand it. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the array of voting booleans isn't bad. But if you want a different approach you can do things with class manipulation to keep them separate.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0uw83a17/

```
// From https://plainjs.com/javascript/traversing/get-siblings-of-an-element-40/
function getSiblings(el, filter) {
    var siblings = [];
    el = el.parentNode.firstChild;
    do { if (!filter || filter(el)) siblings.push(el); } while (el = el.nextSibling);
    return siblings;
}

function classFilter(el) {
    return el.classList && el.classList.contains('active-vote');
}

function handleVote(type, el) {
    let siblings = getSiblings(el, classFilter);

    if (el.classList.contains('active-vote')) {
        el.style.color = "dimgray";
        el.classList.remove('active-vote');
        return -1 * type;
    } else if (siblings.length === 1) {
        el.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
        siblings[0].style.color = "dimgray";
        siblings[0].classList.remove('active-vote');
        el.classList.add('active-vote');

        return 2 * type;
    } else if (!el.classList.contains('active-vote')) {
        el.style.color = "#3CBC8D";
        el.classList.add('active-vote');
        return type;
    }

    return 0;
}

const up_vote_span = document.getElementsByClassName('up-vote');
const down_vote_span = document.getElementsByClassName('down-vote');
const count = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

for (let i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  up_vote_span[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) + handleVote(1, up_vote_span[i]);
    });

  down_vote_span[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      count[i].innerHTML = parseInt(count[i].innerHTML) + handleVote(-1, down_vote_span[i]);
  });
};
```

Comment: I think that your code relies on the fact that all the systems are next to each other. I did this to simplify my code for presenting my problem. In reality the system is not stacked one on top the other. I'm sorry for not being more specific.